# How to define Nestjs dynamic module for Authentication with Passport

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport

i'm trying to create a library to share my auth module between projects. I have 2 params to set in the Strategy (issuer and audience) to configure my project with the right identity server to validate the jwt. I have followed https://dev.to/nestjs/advanced-nestjs-how-to-build-completely-dynamic-nestjs-modules-1370 to implement it, but the method registerAsync don't work as expected (says "Unknown authentication strategy "jwt"") in the console when trying to call an authenticated API). However the register method works fine. Can someone help me? I share with u the code

[AuthModule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkXV6.png)

[Strategy Provider to register with params from ConfigService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPrfT.png)

[How i use registerAsync method in app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiduy.png)

Comment: Could you please put your code in code blocks? It's hard to read and can't be searched.

Comment: the code is in the images added at the end of the question (added with links)